# Parsing information from text file input into JSON format

Tags: javascript, regex, filereader

I'm attempting to parse a text input file in JavaScript.
I want to first break the file into sections which I will then use to fill in a form by adding to the following code snippet.
I'm trying to find a way to to break the input into 5 sections; contact info (name, phone, email), objective, key skills, employment history, and education.
 And here in lies the problem. I'm no regex expert. Looking around the web I couldn't find any lightweight javaScript libraries to help out with this. It would make sense to look for keywords such as **name:**, then match all characters until another keyword is encountered, like **phone:** but I don't quite know how to approach this problem.

```
function controller() {

function loadFromFile(event) {
    var fileInput = event.target.files[0];
    var textType = /txt.*/;

    if (fileInput.type.match(textType)) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function(evt) {
            errorLogger('cannot_read_file', 'The file specified cannot be read ');
        };
        reader.readAsText(fileInput);
    } else {}
}
$(':input[type="file"]').change(loadFromFile);
};
```

`Name: John Doe`
`Phone: (555) 555-5555`
`Email: johndoe@example.com`

```
OBJECTIVE  Excel in a web developer career.

KEY SKILLS Development: HTML5, JavaScript, Bootstrap, AngularJS, ReactJS, CSS3, Media Queries, 
Development Project Management: JIRA, Bitbucket, Confluence, Git, GitHub

EMPLOYMENT HISTORY 
Title: Junior Web Developer 
Company: Apple Inc.  
Dates: June 2015 to September 2016
* Developed responsive corporate websites
* Did some cool stuff
* Led team in closing out JIRA bugs

Title: Web Development Intern  
Company: Google Inc. 
Dates: January 2015 to May 2015
* Went on coffee runs for the team
* Team record for longest keg stand
* Once ate 82 cupcakes during a team building event

EDUCATION Degree: BBA  
School: Michigan State University 
GPA: 2.2 Major: 
Computer Science Minor: Drinking
```

Answer (score 1):

This regex works, provided the input is always the same exact format.

`/Name: ([a-zA-Z ]+)\nPhone: (\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4})\nEmail: (.+@.+)\n{2}OBJECTIVE (.*)\n{2}KEY SKILLS (.*)\n{2}EMPLOYMENT HISTORY ((?:(?:(?:\W+|\s+|.*))*))/g;`

https://regex101.com/r/Q5OUFw/2

I'm not the best with javascript, but this seems to return an array full of matches.

```
let m;
let matches =[];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null)
{
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex)
    {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => { 
    matches.push(match);
    });
}
```

Provides 7 group matches.

`matches[0]` = Full Match

`matches[1]` = Name

`matches[2]` = Phone Number

`matches[3]` = Email

`matches[4]` = Objective

`matches[5]` = Skills

`matches[6]` = Employment history